# Type error: function() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im new to python and im trying to write algorithm to find the longest sub string without repeating characters. I keep getting this Error: " lengthOfLongestSubstring() missing 1 required positional argument: 's' ", when i obviously call the function with the argument. why is it heppening? Thanks for any help.

```
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
        arr = [char1 for char1 in s]
        help_arr = [i*0 for i in range(26)]
        sub_strings = []
        sub = ""
        for char in s:
            index = ord(char) - ord('a')
            if help_arr[index] == 0:
                help_arr[index] = int(1)
                sub += char
            else:
                sub_strings.append(sub)
                sub = ""
                sub += char
                help_arr = [i * 0 for i in range(26)]
                help_arr[index] = int(1)
        max(sub_strings)


    def max(arr):
        max = 0
        index = -1
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            if len(arr[i]) > max:
                max = len(arr[i])
                index=  i
        return print("The answer is '{}', with the length of {}.".format(arr[index], max))

    #call to function
    lengthOfLongestSubstring("aabcdefffgges")
```

Comment: Try to call it like this `self.lengthOfLongestSubstring("aabcdefffgges")`

Comment: Why does the class `Solution` exist at all? All the methods can be defined as regular functions.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: " lengthOfLongestSubstring() missing 1 required positional argument: 's' "

Look at how you define this function:

```
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
```

This requires two arguments, but when you call it, you only pass one:

```
lengthOfLongestSubstring("aabcdefffgges")
```

In this case, you can solve the problem by not using a `class`. It isn't needed for what you are doing. This also means you need to remove the `self` parameter from `lengthOfLongestSubstring()`:

```
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(s):
    arr = [char1 for char1 in s]
    help_arr = [i*0 for i in range(26)]
    sub_strings = []
    sub = ""
    for char in s:
        index = ord(char) - ord('a')
        if help_arr[index] == 0:
            help_arr[index] = int(1)
            sub += char
        else:
            sub_strings.append(sub)
            sub = ""
            sub += char
            help_arr = [i * 0 for i in range(26)]
            help_arr[index] = int(1)
    max(sub_strings)


def max(arr):
    max = 0
    index = -1
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if len(arr[i]) > max:
            max = len(arr[i])
            index=  i
    print("The answer is '{}', with the length of {}.".format(arr[index], max))

#call to function
lengthOfLongestSubstring("aabcdefffgges")
```

On a side note, you should not do `return print(...)`. `return` here doesn't do anything useful, so I removed id.